# Where, if anywhere, should the colon/semi-colons go in this sentence?

Tags: semicolons, colons

> Details about the costs (if any) of starting up the service and maintaining it, spreading awareness and gaining a user base, timelines, or counsel on any other challenges you faced and think might be helpful to us, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Golden Rule of the Semicolon: if you are not absolutely certain it should be there, it is absolutely certain it should not.

Comment: Perhaps the only punctuation mark more terrifying than the semicolon is the colon. Most writers avoid both of them for fear of misusing it and other readers feel intimidated by the brave writer who dared try to master their nuances.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine once you remove the last comma.

> Details about the costs (if any) of starting up the service and
>   maintaining it, spreading awareness and gaining a user base,
>   timelines, or counsel on any other challenges you faced and think
>   might be helpful to us would be greatly appreciated.

The structure of this long sentence is

> A, B, C, or D would be greatly appreciated.